# How to create a test for Fluent nHibernate conventions?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, fluent-nhibernate, conventions

I am creating a [set of conventions for Fluent nHibernate](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions). I create a few conventions, like primary key, foreign key and many-to-many table.

I would like to be able to test out these conventions with an in memory database to see if I coded these conventions correctly.

Currently, I am setting up nHibernate using an SQlite in-memory database like this:

```
Configuration configuration = null;

var factory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
    .Mappings(m => 
        {
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<DataLayer>();
            m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<DataLayer>();
        })
    .ExposeConfiguration((c) => configuration = c)
    .BuildSessionFactory();

var session = factory.OpenSession();

var export = new SchemaExport(configuration);
export.Execute(true, true, false, session.Connection, null);
```

I create a test case, but I don't know test a naming convention. How can I achieve some unit tests on a conventions using a Visual Studio test project?

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. But would like to test configurations of the columns as attributes `StringLength` and `Required` in DataAnnotation.   Did you find any solution?

Comment: I did not find any solution. I don't work at the same place anymore and the project never took off.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is not testing against the database, but just test the generated mapping. So for example I have a convention that says that all foreign keys are written like ID and I test it like (I use xunit and not mstest, but hopefully you can get the concept...):

```
    [Fact]
    public void AddDefaultConventions_ShouldNameMappingToForeinKeyCorrectly()
    {
        var configuration = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008)
        .Mappings(m =>
        {
            m.FluentMappings.Conventions.Add(new CustomForeignKeyConvention());
            m.FluentMappings.Add<TestClassMap>();
            m.FluentMappings.Add<TestClass2Map>();
        })
        .BuildConfiguration();
        var typeMapping = configuration.GetClassMapping(typeof(TestClass2));
        var property = typeMapping.GetProperty("Parent");
        Assert.Equal("ParentID", property.ColumnIterator.First().Text);
    }

    private class TestClass
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    }

    private class TestClass2
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual TestClass Parent { get; set; }
    }

    private class TestClassMap : ClassMap<TestClass>
    {
        public TestClassMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.ID);
        }
    }

    private class TestClass2Map : ClassMap<TestClass2>
    {
        public TestClass2Map()
        {
            Id(x => x.ID);
            References(x => x.Parent);
        }
    }
```

Btw. it wouldn't be too difficult to test against a DB, just try to select something from TestClass2 and make sure no exception is thrown... but I think the way I showed is easier and I trust that when FluentNhibernate can generate the correct NHibernate mapping, NHibernate can generate the correct queries for me.